# How to create tabitem headers from itemsource/list in c# and WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I am trying to create a header for tabitem when there is an observable collection from JSON file as shown in the code below.

```
// Deserialize the JSON array into a List<ModelClass>
List<Model> dataList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(messagecontent);

// Convert List<ModelClass> to ObservableCollection<ModelClass>
ObservableCollection<Model> observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Model>(dataList);

Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    TabitemSub.Items.Clear();
    TabitemSub.ItemsSource = observableCollection;

    foreach (var item in observableCollection)
    {
        TabItem tabitem = new TabItem();
        tabitem.Header = item.property1;
        TabitemSub.Items.Add(tabitem);
    } 
}
```

My Xaml:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="TabitemMain">
        <TabControl x:Name="TabitemSub" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5">
        </TabControl>
    </TabItem>
```

but every time I run the code instead of giving me a string of property1 I keep on getting the path of the model, like project.MVVM.Model.Model in each result of item. Why is that happening and how can I resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: First of all, you must not use Items and ItemsSource at that same time.

Comment: @clemens well, I keep on getting this error if I removed the items.clear (`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.'`)

Comment: Then your XAML is invalid. Add the relevant parts of it to your question.

Comment: @Clemens I added the xaml check the question

Comment: Why are you adding a TabItem in XAML? And what is tabcontrol in code when there is TabitemSub in XAML?

Comment: You want to have a `TabControl.ItemContainerStyle` with `<Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding property1}"/>`

Comment: @Clemens I want to add them to the tabcontrol (which is the TabitemSub)

Comment: @Clemens Managed to solve the issue, see the answer

Comment: Not great. There should be an appropriate ItemContainerStyle in XAML, as already said. You should usually not be creating UI elements in code behind.

Comment: @Clemens Well I was aiming to make this dynamic depending on how many values are there in the property1

Comment: That has nothing to do with the code and XAML in your question. You are creating a TabItem with Header set to property1 for each element in datalist. That could as well be done by assigning `ItemsSource = datalist` and the Style Setter shown above. I've added that to your answer.

Comment: @Clemens I see. tried your approach and got the same results. Thank you, I have like side question. Is it possible to add datagrid to the tabitem in code behind and to have a datagrid to be returned from a function and then use that datagrid to be inserted to the tabitem?

Comment: Sure, you would perhaps revert to creating the TabItems programatically and set a DataGrid as their Content. You should however consider declaring a ContentTemplate with a DataGrid in XAML and bind the DataGrid's ItemsSource to a property of the Model class.

Comment: @Clemens oh okay so I use my approach but do I need to do the same as your step for doing ContentTemplate in xaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to get it to work, if I make the following changes:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    TabitemSub.Items.Clear();

    foreach (Model item in datalist)
    {
        TabItem tabitem = new TabItem();
        tabitem.Header = item.property1;
        TabitemSub.Items.Add(tabitem);
    } 
}
```

then it will create tabs for each property1 value.

---

This should however be done without creating UI elements in code behind, by means of an ItemContainerStyle or the DisplayMemberPath property like

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabitemSub" ...>
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding property1}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

or

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabitemSub" DisplayMemberPath="property1" .../>
```

and

```
TabitemSub.ItemsSource = datalist;
```